# Getting IE7 to render using standards AND quirks box mode

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, quirks-mode

I'm a big fan of IE's buggy box model, and I'm really glad to see that in CSS 3
the box model is something that we can specify.

So my question is:  Can I get IE7 to keep it's best standards but retain it's quirks mode for the box model.

Otherwise i'm stuck with a separate CSS style sheet for IE7

Comment: I could be wrong, but I'm pretty sure it's an all-or-nothing thing.

Comment: Why would you want to render anything non-standard?

Comment: You can't. Another reason to bury IE7.

Comment: well that old box model is something I certainly prefer and can get for modern browsers with the css 3 box-size setting

Answer (score 0):

Use one of the quirksmode stylesheets and copy those styles into a [media query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3043094/is-there-any-ie8-only-css-hack/8812829#8812829) to emulate the box model in one file:

- [quirk.css](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/layout/style/quirk.css)
- [quirks.css](http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Source/WebCore/css/quirks.css)